# Can a SVM be used to differentiate samples ?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

On the problem I'm working for, I need to know if two samples are similar.

I'd like a class 1 when the two samples are similar and class 0 when they are not.

I don't know how to explain it better, so here is stupid example:

Training set: {A,B},{C,D},E
Results: AB:1,AC:0,AD:0,AE:0,BA:1,BC:0,BD:0,BE:0,...

I thought of just giving the two sets of features concatenated to the svm, but the problem would then be that the memory necessary is O(n²) which is too big :(

Is there any way to solve this kind of problem with a SVM ?

P.S. I know I could use labels, that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Whenever you think about applying machine learning the first thing you want to find out is: `what function do I want the method to learn` - In your case this could be a distance function. The second, more difficult question is: `Can this function be learned from examples`. So: Is it possible  to extract data from a couple of examples and then come up with a reasonable approximation of `f`. We cannot tell for sure, that depends on your data/problem...

Comment: I could not understand your problem. consider to refine your description to increase the chance of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating samples is classification which is what SVMs do. If you don't want to label your data, you won't be able to apply supervised learning though. Depending on your specific problem you'd then choose an unsupervised learning algorithm.

However, make sure you understand what 'labeling' means. When you say

> Results: AB:1,AC:0,AD:0,AE:0,BA:1,BC:0,BD:0,BE:0,...

then that **is** giving your data (binary) labels. If you're able to define what similarity is and provide training data, you can use supervised learning.

Also, keep in mind that a space complexity of Ω(n²) is not something you'll be able to beat with most machine learning techniques since a high number of approaches use matrices to represent data and/or learn. Experience has rather shown that it's not impractical.